# problems with refreshing GLSL canvas in React app

Tags: reactjs, canvas, glsl

I have implemented a Glsl canvas background in a React Comp and it refuses to refresh on reload (hacky i know)

i've tried both the commented out stuff and the other version.....

i am basically having issues where the background doesn't resize when the screen is enlarged, but it works fine when its shrunk down.  So i tried to reload the canvas as a way to fix but its not working.

```
  const resizer = (canvas, container) => {
    // canvas.width = container.clientWidth + window.devicePixelRatio;
    // canvas.height = container.clientHeight + window.devicePixelRatio;
    // canvas.style.width = container.clientWidth + "px";
    // canvas.style.height = container.clientHeight + "px";
    setReloaded(true);
    if (reloaded) {
      location.reload();
    }
  };
```

i get this error is vs code :

GLSL Lint: Failed to spawn 'glslangValidator' binary. Error: spawn glslangValidator ENOENT

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It was a really stupid error.  I had not set the width of the container in the css.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).